# Android: OnCreate() method is not calling while click on back button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am facing a very strange problem. In my activity when i press Back button its not calling a onCreate() method of parent activity.

Here is my code:
                  public class AddNewGrocery extends Activity{

```
 private DBHelper mydb ;
 Button btnSave;
 EditText editName;
 EditText editQty;
 EditText editPrice;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setTitle("Add List Item Details");



    /** Setting a custom layout for the list activity */
    setContentView(R.layout.add_grocery);
     btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    editQty=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtqty);
    editPrice=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
```

}}

Here is a code of my mainfeast file:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.grocerylist.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.grocerylist.AddNewList"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:parentActivityName="com.example.grocerylist.MainActivity">
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.grocerylist.AddNewGrocery"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.grocerylist.AddNewList">
     </activity>
```

Comment: Did any of these answers help you out?

Answer (score 3):

It is because the parent activity is already created but it is paused when accessing to another activity. If you want to perform some tasks when returning to the activity, you might use 'onResume()' method.

See documenation: [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Comment: onResume() worked for me, @Developer, can you mark this answer correct?

Comment: onStart() also seems to get called.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the previous activity is still in memory, thus has already been created. Instead, onResume() is called. [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) This explains what is called each in different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the back button is only guaranteed to call the onPause() method. If you want onCreate() to be called each time you resume your app, you could put onStop(), in your overridden onPause() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the onResume method in your code

```
public void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
// do stuff
}
```